# How to suppress legends with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following `ggplot` code:

```
ggplot(Wheat_by_yearContinent, aes(x = Year, y = avgWheatYield, color = ContinentName)) + 
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
  geom_line(size = 1) + 
  expand_limits(y = 0) + 
  ggtitle("Wheat") + 
  ylab(bquote('Average Yield ( '*'ton'~ ha^-1*')'))
```

and I have tried a few ways to suppress the legend but can't seem to figure it out and nothing I have tried is doing anything. Has anyone encountered this problem/know how to do this? I have included `+ theme(legend.position = "none")` in the above code as this was my final attempt, I also tried `legend = FALSE` and nothing there either.

Comment: Bookmark this website and specifically answering your question: a few ways to do it
http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_(ggplot2)/

Comment: It would be easier to help you out with more information, such as a reproducible example. Do you experience the same using a simpler dataset such as `mtcars` (`ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = hp, col = cyl)) + geom_point() + theme(legend.position = "none")`)? Which version of `R`are you using? is your package updated? It is hard to help you out with only the information provided.

Comment: @Oliver I will include these in my future questions posted to this SE page, thank you for pointing out things I was missing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried some of the these?

Remove legend from a particular aesthetic:

```
plot + guides(colour=FALSE)
```

or

Remove legend inside geom_line():

```
geom_line(aes(...), show.legend = FALSE))
```

Comment: Works great in `geom_smooth(..., show.legend=FALSE)` for getting rid of the unwanted default blue line that shows up in the legend.